# .Net 3.5 on i7 multicore processor

Tags: c#, .net, multicore

Are there any known issues with .NET 3.5 running on i7 multicore processors? 
Does the .NET framework/compiler automatically take advantage of the multiple cores or does it have to be explicitly programmed to do so?

Comment: Have you encountered a problem regarding the I7? Or at least a rumor?

Comment: Look here: [Parallel programming in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2263803/791745)

Comment: I have not had any problems, we have a client who wants to set up a server to use our solution. They wanted to know if i7 will work or not. I have not had any experience with i7 and decided to be safe and ask :)

Answer (score 7):

No, none.

As for threading - you have to write your code to use threads.

Since you also asked about the compiler - you can enable [parallel builds on multicore machines in MSBuild](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FasterBuildsWithMSBuildUsingParallelBuildsAndMulticoreCPUs.aspx) if you're feeling adventurous and if your solutions are suitable to be parallelized.

Comment: Agreed, I have an i7 laptop and have had no issues with 3.0/3.5/4.0.

Answer (score 0):

There's no issue with running .NET 3.5 on an i7 that I'm aware of.

The .NET Framework has support for building multi-threaded applications, but will not inherently change its behaviour for the presence of multiple CPU cores.

However, certain application hosts, such as IIS are themselves multi-threaded and are able to distribute workloads across multiple threads (and thus, execute them in parallel across multiple cores) without you necessarily having to make your code thread-aware.

The other way to exploit multiple cores is to simply run more processes.

You have a world of possibilities and it's up to you to decide how to exploit them!

Answer (score 0):

I have three computers with i7, using and programming .NET 3.5 on all of them. Never heard of an issue with it. If you want to program with .NET to leverage the multi-cores, I suggest looking at the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). Also see this book, [Parallel Programming with Microsoft .NET](http://parallelpatterns.codeplex.com/).